# Get list based on condition from another generic list

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 classes called `Config` and `ClassField`. The config class has a *generic* list of `ClassFields`. `ClassFields` has a *generic* list of strings called `ClassErrors`.

I have a `List<Config>` in a variable and would like to get only the Configs which do not have any Class Errors.

I have tried the following code but just can't seem to get it right.

```
var list = _lstSyncConfigs.Where(f => f.SyncConfigClassFields.Where(g => g.AttributeErrors.Count == 0).Select(f).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe what you are looking for. `Where` > `All` > *not* `Any`

```
var list = _lstSyncConfigs.Where(f => f.SyncConfigClassFields.All(g => !g.AttributeErrors.Any()))
                          .ToList();
// or

var list = _lstSyncConfigs.Where(f => f.SyncConfigClassFields.All(g => g.AttributeErrors.Count == 0))
                          .ToList()
```

<sub>***Note*** : If one of your lists has the potential to be null, you might wont to use the [Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)</sub>

Comment: you may also safely check for `g.AttributeErrors.Count == 0` instead of `!g.AttributeErrors.Any()` as the `g.AttributeErrors` is a `List<string>`